# How to select hierarchical static fields in Excel using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, excel

I need to get pivot data table based on FY'19 . 
Here i am using power pivotTable but when it is inside the if loop the commented part is giving me error.

```
while (index <= System.Convert.ToInt32(oPivotTable.CubeFields.Count))
            {
                if (oPivotTable.CubeFields[index].Name.ToString().Equals("[Range].[Task Closed Fiscal Yr]"))
                {
                    CubeField1 = oPivotTable.CubeFields[index];
                    CubeField1.Orientation = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlPageField;
                     //Facing issue in below code  
                    CubeField1.CurrentPageName = String.Format("[{0}].[{1}].&[{2}]", "Task Age Summary", "Task Closed Fiscal Yr", "FY'19");  
                }

                index += 1;

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to comment but don't have enough rep ....

I ditched Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel a while ago in favour of the fantastic NuGet package EPPlus

https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/wiki/Getting-Started

Unfortunately the docs are pending on Pivot Tables at the moment but there are some examples.

https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/blob/master/SampleApp/Sample12.cs

I have used this package for many Excel read/write operations and find it very easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

After applying record macro and doing some testing on the same i am able to solve the answer. I need to remove curly braces     CubeField2.CurrentPageName = "[Range].[Task Status].&[Closed-Complete]";
                    }